# Repository pattern, one interface, multiple classes

Tags: c#

Given this code

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    IQueryable<T> GetAll();
}
```

and this

```
public class XmlProductRepository : IRepository<Product>
{
    private const string RelativePath = "~/data/products.xml";

    public string Filename { get; private set; }
    public XmlLoader Loader { get; private set; }

    public XmlProductRepository(HttpContextBase httpContext, XmlLoader loader)
    {
        Filename = httpContext.Server.MapPath(RelativePath);
        Loader = loader;
    }

    public IQueryable<Product> GetAll()
    {
        return Loader.Load<ProductCollection>(Filename).AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

what would you do to support many object types (apart from Product, additional 20 types like Plugin, Extension, Page, Section, etc.)? The implementation of the interface is the same for all object types, the only thing that is different is the RelativePath - we want to save different types into different folders organised by their type name, like so

- ~/data/Product/...
- ~/data/Plugin/...
- ~/data/Page/...

**So assume the only thing that changes is the path. Obviously we don't want to make a repository class for each one of those object types and copy the same code into each one of those classes.** We just want to construct the path based on the object used for T.

Comment: What is *ProductCollection*? It seems we have to implement *GetAll()* for each type because of the different collections ...

Comment: No we don't need to because this gets loaded by the XmlLoader class which performs deserialization so this is worked out fine.

Comment: Actually you were right about it but this code piece is actually not the right implementation of GetAll(). Instead of ProductCollection there will be a base collection class that all specific collections inherit from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you make the XmlRepository generic and use `typeof` to get the name of the xml file?

```
public class XmlRepository<T> : IRepository<T>
{
    private readonly string RelativePath;

    public string Filename { get; private set; }
    public XmlLoader Loader { get; private set; }

    public XmlRepository( HttpContextBase httpContext, XmlLoader loader )
    {
        RelativePath = string.Format( "~/data/{0}.xml" + typeof( T ).Name );
        Filename = httpContext.Server.MapPath( RelativePath );
        Loader = loader;
    }

    public IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return Loader.Load<List<T>>( Filename ).AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've already tried it this way but then I have some issues when trying to use Ninject for IoC, for instance Ninject rules need to be written like this:
Bind<IRepository<Product>>().To<XmlProductRepository>().InSingletonScope();

This won't work
Bind<IRepository<Product>>().To<XmlRepository<Product>>().InSingletonScope();

Comment: you could create XmlProductRepository from XmlRepository<Product>, not ideal but your implementations would be minimal.

Comment: Does it work if you create little wrappers? ie. `public class XmlProductsRepository : XmlRepository<Product>`?

Comment: This would lead to way to many classes and files, it's working workaround/hack but I would like to avoid it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Ninject, but it would seem like it is forcing you to create a wrapper no matter what. Creating wrappers would at least put all of the similar code in one place. It probably goes against your standards, but if you are worried about creating a lot of files you could put all of the simple wrapper classes in the same file as they can all be one line long. I'd probably put them in the top of the file that defines the XmlRepository base class.

Comment: @Jerod: Making wrapper classes indeed works at compile time though I don't know if it will work at runtime, hopefully it will, I cannot try it out just now. I'm accepting your answer.

Comment: @mare, You might try using the Ninject Bind `.ToMethod` and then using reflection to get the `XmlRepository<T>` via `(typeof(XmlRepository<>).MakeGenericType` and `Activator.CreateInstance`.  It's a bit of a hack, but it might accomplish what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class XmlRepository<TEntityType> : IRepository<TEntityType> 
{ 

Type t = typeof(TEntityType);
private const string RelativePath = String.Format("~/data/{0}.xml",t.Name); 

public string Filename { get; private set; } 
public XmlLoader Loader { get; private set; } 

public XmlProductRepository(HttpContextBase httpContext, XmlLoader loader) 
{ 
    Filename = httpContext.Server.MapPath(RelativePath); 
    Loader = loader; 
} 

public IQueryable<TEntityType> GetAll() 
{ 
    return Loader.Load<List<TEntityType>>(Filename).AsQueryable(); 
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could create an abstract base class, like:

```
public abstract class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>
{
    public string Filename { get; private set; }
    public XmlLoader Loader { get; private set; }

    protected Repository<T>(HttpContextBase httpContext, XmlLoader loader, string relativePath)
    {
        Filename = httpContext.Server.MapPath(relativePath));
        Loader = loader;
    }

    public abstract IQueryable<T> GetAll();
}
```

XmlProductRepository:

```
public class XmlProductRepository : Repository<Product>
{
    public XmlProductRepository(HttpContextBase httpContext, XmlLoader loader)
             : base( httpContext, loader, "~/data/products.xml" ) {}

    public IQueryable<Product> GetAll()
    {
        return Loader.Load<ProductCollection>(Filename).AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it seems, that you need to specify *ProductCollection* --> implement *GetAll()*. Without this *ProductCollection* you could move the *GetAll()* method to the base class as well.

Comment: GetAll() is just one of the methods, there will be many methods and we don't want to repeat them across different files - maintainence hell and bad practice.